# how to create new subfolder in git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a to add files in new subdirectory tothe existing repo... Say I have a repo http://myrepo.git with folder `work` and I have to add new files in folder `subject` under `work`. I found docs to explain how to add project to repo:

```
cd subject
git init
git add .
git commit
git remote add origin http://myrepo.git
git remote -v; git push origin master
```

But this seems to be designed to add my files to `myrepo.git`, how can I keep 
`myrepo.git/work/subject` directory structure?
Thanks

Comment: The "subject" directory is not empty, i have several new files there

Answer (score 2):

You can't add an empty directory to git.

The general workaround is to add an empty file `.gitkeep` and to add it to git:

```
touch work/subject/.gitkeep
git add work/subject/.gitkeep
git commit -am "Add directory subject"
```

That way, the directory will exist, and you know can remove this file once you have other ones in this directory.

Comment: Maybe emphasize that adding a directory is fundamentally the same as adding a file, except that adding an empty directory is a pesky special case.

Comment: @tripleee You can emphasize whatever you want but that [doesn't make it true](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F). You simply cannot add directories at all.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a to add files in new subdirectory tothe existing repo...
>
> The "subject" directory is not empty, i have several new files there

I think you are doing it completely wrong, there is no need to create a fresh git repository and add files to it. Instead, you can add files to the original repo itself:

```
git clone  myrepo.git
cd work 
mkdir subject && cd subject && touch file1 file2 #touch is equivalent to new files added
git add . && git commit -m "some message"
git push origin master
```

The above should push your changes to the remote, and as you can clearly see, there is no new repo created in the process.

Comment: got it, my error is exactly what mu said: trying to add it as new repo with git init...

Answer (score 0):

Got it, my error is exactly what mu said: trying to add it as new repo with git init..

```
 git clone myrepo.git
 cd work && mkdir subject && cp myfiles to subject && cp subject
 git add . && git commit -m "some message"
 git push
```

This will push myfiles into myrepo.git under work/subject